# Wordpress URL rewrite with custom $_GET variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to rewrite a URL similar to wordpress where:

```
http://www.example.com/?p=5
```

becomes

```
http://www.example.com/some-page-with-that-title
```

I'd like

```
http://www.example.com/events/?event_id=23
```

to become

```
http://www.example.com/events/some-event-title
```

I've discovered the wordpress rewrite api and have successfully gotten the following to rewrite the url using and events template page.

```
add_action( 'init', 'events_permalinks' );
function events_permalinks() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'events/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=events&event_name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
);
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'events_query_vars' );
function events_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'event_name';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

And get the variable with
get_query_var( 'event_name' )

I know I need to look up the event_id in the non-wordpress events table to get the name but I'm not sure where to put the query so I can swap it into the url. Hopefully I haven't confused things. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really an expert on rewritting but if you are only using a single $_GET var this snippet will work for you (at least it worked for me). As you can see rewrite sintax is a little bit diferent on the way you reference the $_GET parameter.

Your code also worked for me on a multiple $_GET var context, not in a single one. Hope this work for you, rembember to update your permalinks going to Settings → Permalinks Screen → Save Changes.

More info: [Wordpress Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
 | [Wordpress Permalinks Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Automatically_updating_.htaccess)

```
    add_action('init', 'events_permalinks');

    function events_permalinks(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
            '^events/([^/]*)$',
            'index.php?pagename=events&event_name=$matches[1]',
            'top'
            );
    }

    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'events_query_vars' );
    function events_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars[] = 'event_name';
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

The URLs in WordPress can be easily customised in your dashboard. See the [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) article from WordPress Codex.

Comment: I read that article.  It doesn't really apply to my question for custom $_GET variables just wordpress variables like %post_id% etc.